# When to reply the email of a job offer?

Tags: job-search, email, negotiation

I got an email with a written job offer for a faculty position in the US. A question that I never saw addressed is about the timing of replying to a written offer email.

Should I acknowledge and thank for their email immediately and say that I will consider the details of the offer and then reach out to them again, or should I only reply to them whenever I decide if I accept/decline/ask-to-negotiate the offer?

Comment: I guess I'd say that I'm very surprised that nobody called you to give you a verbal offer before the email.

Comment: @JonCuster me ttoo, I was expecting a verbal mention of salary so I could negotiate before the written offer was made. This makes me concerned

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When I was in this position, I answered the email immediately thanking them for the offer, taking the time to interview me and for the excellent opportunity it would be to work at [university]. I told them that I would review the offer and get back to them soon.

My reasoning is that email is fickle and life is messy. Does silence mean you are thinking about the offer? Does it mean you’re on vacation? You’re in the hospital? Or does it mean the email attachment got stuck in the spam system? I think acknowledgement is the polite thing to do. And I don’t think you lose anything towards bargaining.

Comment: Thanks. This was indeed what I ended up doing. I liked your approach and your insight was very much appreciated.